# Using Curl in Batch to control HTML elements

Tags: html, windows, batch-file, web, curl

I am currently trying to figure out a way to press a button on a website by simply using a batch file.

Specifically, I want to "control" the play button of a radio player, (best case: without displaying the page).

I believe this is the HTML element of the play button:

```
<svg class="icon icon-play-2016" id="gl-pl-play">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-play-2016" id="gl-pl-play"> </use>
</svg>
```

I searched online and found that the [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) command could be used somehow, but my attempt of using it didn't succeed:

```
@echo on
start https://www.radio.de/s/antennemuenster
curl -s -w "%%{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}" https://www.radio.de/s/antennemuenster
exit
```

Comment: @TimRech You should extract the stream `http://swr-edge-20bc.fra-lg.cdn.addradio.net/swr/swr1/bw/mp3/128/stream.mp3`

Comment: @Hackoo okay, I see. That's a useful tip. I just looked through the html script and filtered for something similar. But no luck there. Maybe I would need a tool to extract the audio from the url?

Comment: @Hackoo Nvmd, this was easier than I thought. So the extracted audio is this: http://mms.hoerradar.de/am128k. Now I just need to find a way of controling the play button while hiding the tab in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract the stream by another tool in my case i can extract with `IDM : Internet Downloader Manager`

And you can write it with a batch file that use a vbscript to play the stream :

```
@echo off
Title Welcome to the world of the music
Mode 50,3 & color 9E
echo(
echo        Welcome to the world of the music
Rem Just change this variable MusciPath
Set MusicPath=http://mms.hoerradar.de/am128k
rem http://swr-edge-20bc.fra-lg.cdn.addradio.net/swr/swr1/bw/mp3/128/stream.mp3
Call :Play "%MusicPath%"
Pause>nul & Exit
::---------------------------------------------------------------
:Play
Set "VBS_MUSIC=%temp%\SWR1_Radio.vbs"
(
    echo Play "%~1"
    echo Sub Play(MusicPath^)
    echo    Dim Sound
    echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
    echo    Sound.URL = MusicPath
    echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    echo    Sound.Controls.play
    echo    While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
    echo        WScript.Sleep 100
    echo    Wend
    echo End Sub
)>"%VBS_MUSIC%"
Cscript //NoLogo "%VBS_MUSIC%"
exit /b
::---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Wow... You're an actual genius! That is neat. Didn't know you could create an VBS just like that within cmd. Now I think I pretty much understood what you are doing here. Only one question left. Do you mean I should convert the stream with another tool so I could create a VBS script that has some gui for play and pause or what is the matter with the current stream? Thanks so much again!